# an object - which is arraylist<string> - gives NullPointerException error

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I created a class to make an object which is an `ArrayList<String>` of 4 elements - they are picked as a series of random elements of another `ArrayList<String>` and they need to be unique.

When I run the app and an object is created, the next step is to get into the object and take out the elements and use each of them - unfortunately at the first element LogCat gives me `fatal error - NullPointerException` and says the `null` is in set method of the class where random elements of the `bigger` arraylist are added to the one that is supposed to be populated by the setter.

I don't understand why - the same code used to generate random elements inside an activity works fine but I want to do it with an object because it will be done a few times. I have tried to do it different ways but the result was the same every time. Perhaps I made a stupid mistake or I missed something. I will appreciate any help. The code is below...

The class:

```
public class QuizSetGenerator {

    private ArrayList<String> set;

    QuizSetGenerator(ArrayList<String> list) {
        this.SetQuizSet(list);   //second Null Pointed in logcat
    }

    public void SetQuizSet(ArrayList<String> a) {
        //option 1
        Random rand = new Random();
        /*int[] index = new int[4];
        boolean repeats = false;
        //get four random numbers 0-a.size and save them in an int array, each of them must be unique
        for(int i=0; i<4; ) {
        index[i] = rand.nextInt(a.size());
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
        if(index[j]==index[i]) {
        repeats = true; break;
        }
        }
        this.set.add(a.get(index[i]));  //First null show in logcat
        i++;
        }*/

        //option2
        int[] n = new int[5];
        boolean repeats = false;
        for(int j=0; j<5; ) {
            do {
                n[j] = rand.nextInt(a.size());
                for(int i=0; i<j; i++) {
                    if(n[i]==n[j]) {
                        repeats = true; break;
                    }
                }
            } while (repeats);
            this.set.add(a.get(n[j]));  //First null shown in logcat
            j++;
        }

        //option3
        /*for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        Collections.shuffle(a);
        this.set.add(a.get(0));  //First null show in logcat
        }*/
    }

    public ArrayList<String> GetQuizSet() {
        return this.set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting your error? How are you calling this? There's no main function. Stack trace please.

Comment: the error is where the new arraylist is populated with randomly picked elements of the 'base' arraylist as I wrote above. I'll add comments in code to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never create set.  You declare it, but never define it to be a new ArrayList().  Without that it doesn't point to a valid reference.